# Extracting certain polygons out of shapefile based on attributes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, select

I have a polygon shapefile that consists of many land use polygons. I want to create a new shapefile that only includes a few land use polygons from the original shapefile. The original shapefile has a "Land_Use" field, and I want to create a new shapefile that includes polygons with a "Developed" and "Building" land use attributes.

What tool can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Select (Analysis)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/select.htm) tool which:

> Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer,
> typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL)
> expression, and stores them in an output feature class.

Your expression could be:

```
Land_Use IN ('Developed', 'Building')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "Select By Attribute". Your query would be:

```
[Land_Use] = "Developed" OR [Land_Use]="Building"
```

Then export the selected data, by right clicking the data in the table of contents (Data>>Export Features)